# How to encourage grade 5 kid very interested in mathematics?

Tags: primary-education, reference-books, gifted-students, book, india

My son is in Class or Grade 5 in India. he really likes mathematics. Apart from school work, he does ixl.com, website dedicated for math exercises of his class.
he does those exercises relatively easily.
i want to encourage him in mathematics,

1. how should i encourage my son, so that he is engaged and curiosity remains ?
2. can anyone suggest math books for him to continue to learn problem solving ?

Comment: Please post answers as answers so they can be upvoted, accepted and get their own comment threads; comments on the question are best for side notes or clarifying questions.

Comment: I felt like my comment was too short to be an answer. But I can move it.

Comment: Related questions: [What books are like Knuth's Surreal Numbers?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10680/3593) and [What are some great books for inspiring children to explore mathematics?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/238/3593). Note that I can't really post this as an answer, because it would be a link-only answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Beast Academy](https://beastacademy.com/) is wonderful. It goes from a level 2 to a level 5, but those are higher than U.S. grade levels. Also, I have some of my favorite books listed [at my blog](https://mathmamawrites.blogspot.com/p/math-books.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [Kahn Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math) is quite extensive, and in my experience of high quality. It is partitioned by grades (kindergarten, 1st, .2nd, .., 8th), and by topic (arithmetic, geometry, pre-algebra, etc.) It has a nice interactive interface, practice questions and levels. A student can have a personalized dashboard. They've now branched out to Economics and AP-Biology among other topics. A non-profit organization.

Comment: I concur. I expected to not like Khan Academy because, frankly, a lot of math education websites are bad, but I was pleasantly surprised. It certainly doesn't hurt that it's free either!